# Property file InputStream ok in Websphere but null in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, properties-file

Though I am  using Websphere majorly but I want to use properties file in a way that works in Tomcat as well. I am initializing `properties` object in a static block for I want to use the `properties` object in static methods.

```
public class Utils {
    public static Properties properties = null;

    static {
        try{
            properties = new Properties();
            String propertiesFile = "../../../../WebContent/path.properties";
            InputStream in = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFile);
            properties.load(in);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code gives following exception in Tomcat, but working like charm in Websphere.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
    at carey.services.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:50)
```

Tips or alterations to suit the need is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that path.properties isn't actually in the "classpath" (compiled into a JAR or located with class files), which is where resources are supposed to live.  It's probably working in Websphere due to side effect of how its class loading works. This doesn't mean it's correct, it's a side effect.

Comment: I am running the web application on Tomcat in Eclipse. I have added the path.properties in build path now. But now I am getting NoClassDefFoundError exception in the controller at a line where Utils class is invoking it's static method.:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.utils.Utils
 at com.test.MyController.myMethod(MyController.java:1997)